# ReSharper - Possible Null Assignment when using Microsoft.Contracts

Tags: c#, resharper, code-contracts, design-by-contract, microsoft-contracts

Is there any way to indicate to ReSharper that a null reference won't occur because of Design-by-Contract Requires checking?  For example, the following code will raise the warning (`Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute`) in ReSharper on lines 7 and 8:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _Lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public void Foo(string s)
{
    Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));

    if (_Lookup.ContainsKey(s))
        _Lookup.Remove(s);
}
```

What is really odd is that if you remove the `Contract.Requires(...)` line, the ReSharper message goes away.

**Update**

I found the solution through ExternalAnnotations which was also mentioned by Mike below.  Here's an example of how to do it for a function in Microsoft.Contracts:

- Create a directory called `Microsoft.Contracts` under the `ExternalAnnotations` ReSharper directory.
- Next, Create a file called `Microsoft.Contracts.xml` and populate like so:

```
<assembly name="Microsoft.Contracts">
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
</assembly>
```

- Restart Visual Studio, and the message goes away!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Note**: as of the current R# 8.0 EAP, this functionality is included.

---

Here's the solution for the current (i.e. .NET 4.0) version of Code Contracts:

Inside `...\ExternalAnnotations\mscorlib\Contracts.xml`, add the following:

```
<assembly name="mscorlib">
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assert(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assert(System.Boolean, System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assume(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assume(System.Boolean, System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires``1(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(System.Boolean,System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires``1(System.Boolean,System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Invariant(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Invariant(System.Boolean,System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
</assembly>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks - this answer helped me REMOVE a chunk from these files that was erroneously giving this warning.

Answer (score 19):

I'd like to add that for people writing their own assertion methods and such, you can include these attributes without an external XML file. In Visual Studio, go to `ReSharper > Options > Code Annotations` and click the `Copy default implementation to clipboard` button. Then create a new file (anywhere you want in your solution) and paste in the code from the clipboard. Now, you can create methods like this:

```
public class Require
{
    [AssertionMethod]
    public static void That(
        [AssertionCondition(AssertionConditionType.IS_TRUE)] 
        bool requiredCondition,
        string message = null)
    {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Now any call to `Require.That(a != null)` will indicate to ReSharper that you can't get past this line if `a` is null.  Unlike the ExternalAnnotations technique, this will work for anyone using your methods, without any additional work on their part.

#### Update

Resharper has changed their contract annotation model as of version 7. Here's what the above method would look like now:

```
public class Require
{
    [ContractAnnotation("requiredCondition:false => halt")]
    public static void That(
        bool requiredCondition,
        string message = null)
    {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I hate myself for not reading all the answers first. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can but it isn't trivial. Take a look at [Resharper online help for code annotation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/index.jsp?Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html)

They annotated the BCL classes and the NUnit framework (and more) to enhance Resharpers code inspection capabilities.

For example with the NUnit asserts they annotated with an AssertionMethodAttribute. This tells Resharpers code inspection that if you got past an Assert.IsNotNull(foo); then foo must not be null and it won't produce the "Possible 'null' assignment..." warning anymore.

You could produce an xml file annotating the Contracts.Requires method to indicate that it is just like an Assert.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the message goes away when you remove the assertion is that R# works in an "optimistic" mode by default. It assumes everything is non-null until you do something that indicates it can actually be null. That's what happens when you add the call to `String.IsNullOrEmpty`. You're stating that `s` could actually be null. It just isn't aware that the `Contract.Requires` method will stop execution if that's the case, but that you solved with the annotation.

In R# 5.0 you can change to a pessimistic mode that assumes the worst at every corner.

Answer (score 3):

I took Porges' XML and added annotations for the Assert and Assume methods. I'll wiki this answer in case other people want to add more methods.

```
<assembly name="mscorlib">
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assert(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assert(System.Boolean, System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assume(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assume(System.Boolean, System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires``1(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(System.Boolean,System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires``1(System.Boolean,System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Invariant(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Invariant(System.Boolean,System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <parameter name="condition">
            <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionAttribute.#ctor(JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionConditionType)">
                <argument>0</argument>
            </attribute>
        </parameter>
    </member>
</assembly>
```

Comment: I've merged this answer into the accepted one, because this got hidden by other answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Resharper has changed their contract annotation model as of version 7.**

You need a different file. The new location (I guess only for Metro apps) is: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\Bin\ExternalAnnotations\.NETCore\System.Diagnostics.Contracts\Contracts.xml"

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and .Net 4.5 and Resharper 7.1.

Content:

```
<assembly name="System.Diagnostics.Contracts">
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assert(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assert(System.Boolean, System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assume(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assume(System.Boolean, System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires``1(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(System.Boolean,System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires``1(System.Boolean,System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Invariant(System.Boolean)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
    <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Invariant(System.Boolean,System.String)">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
            <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
        </attribute>
    </member>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR - Add the conditional compilation symbol `CONTRACTS_FULL` to your project.**

The `Contract.Requires(...)` method is empty and disabled, unless you enable and use the Code Contacts rewriter. By running the rewriter manually, or (usually) enabling it through the Visual Studio project properties, you will keep the `Contract.Requires(...)` code in your compiled and rewritten binaries. You know the code will work, and ignoring the Resharper warning, you can run it and test.

What is the problem then? Resharper doesn't know that the code contracts are running, since they are really only injected at (post-)compile time. In the eyes of Resharper, it's disabled in the same way as the `DEBUG` preprocessor symbol works and how Visual Studio greys out areas of your code that won't be part of your compiled binaries.

```c#
#ifdef DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("I'm in DEBUG mode, so this is probably a Debug build.");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Let's assume this is a Release build.");
#endif
```

According to the [Code Contracts user manual](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/code-contracts/?from=http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) (chapter 2, first paragraph) and the source code in `ContractExtensions.cs` (included in the Code Contracts install folder), `CONTRACTS_FULL` needs to be set before compiling with it. [The Contract methods are actually implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.requires?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) with [`[ConditionalAttribute("CONTRACTS_FULL")]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) and ignored (not included at compile time) unless the flag is set. Resharper respects this flag, and assumes that the function will not run unless it's set.

```c#
[ConditionalAttribute("CONTRACTS_FULL")]
public static void Requires(bool condition) { ... }
```

Solution: Add the conditional compilation symbol `CONTRACTS_FULL` to your project. See [Using Code Contracts Visual Studio and with Resharper](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2010/11/18/Using-Code-Contracts-Visual-Studio-and-with-Resharper.aspx) by Henning Krause.

[image]
<sub>(source: [infinitec.de](http://www.infinitec.de/image.axd?picture=Windows-Live-Writer/Using-CodeContracts-with-Resharper/05970F39/ConditionalSymbol.png))</sub>

The Resharper team has been notified; [Code analysis doesn't consider settings on the 'Code Contracts' project properties tab](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-179286), [Support of Microsoft Code Contracts](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-190566).