# Resharper warns about a null string (System.NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, string, nullreferenceexception, resharper-8.0

Just want to be sure that I haven't been coding for too long ... But, this seems highly unlikely :

[image: string System.NullReferenceException]https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTlwX.png

I create the var, check for null, return if it is, so there's no way I can see it as being null at that point :)

Resharper bug ?

**Edit:**
As per **Igal Tabachnik** answer, he's right, I'm using the following method extension:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string target)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(target);
}
```

I find it much easier to read

```
if (some_string.IsNullOrEmpty())
  // do something here
```

rather than the:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(some_string))
  // do something here
```

**Solution:**
**Igal Tabachnik** was right. The only 2 missing pieces were:

1. Resharper -> Options -> Code Annotations (under Code inspection group) -> turn on for solution.
2. Give VS a couple of minutes to get refresh everything.

Comment: It is not a bug. [ReSharper NullReferenceException Analysis and Its Contracts](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/11/17/resharper-nullreferenceexception-analysis-and-its-contracts/)

Comment: Also: [ReSharper: how to remove “Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'” warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393456/resharper-how-to-remove-possible-system-nullreferenceexception-warning)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code suggests that `IsNullOrEmpty()` method you're using is your own custom Extension method. The "real" `IsNullOrEmpty` is a static method of `string`.

Short answer: if you change it to

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input_string))
    return "...";
```

ReSharper will stop complaining.

Long answer: Since this is your own extension method, ReSharper has no way of knowing how the result of this method applies to your code. For this, ReSharper uses code annotations to figure out additional information about the code. One such annotation is called a [Contract Annotation](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/15/contract-annotations-in-resharper-7/), and it is what ReSharper uses to figure out the result of the original `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` method. You can read more about it in the blog post.

Bottom line, if you want to use your own extension method, but have ReSharper understand it correctly, you have to apply the following Contract Annotation on it:

```
[ContractAnnotation("null=>true")]
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string input)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for solving the problem while keeping his original extension method. And also for Porcupine Tree ;)

Comment: Wow, really nice solution. +1 for sure.

Comment: This is highly interesting :). Your first suggestion is 100% on the money, and using 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(my_string)' get's rid of it. Updated question with my code. The annotation on the extension method though doesn't make the warning go away. I'll go read the links you posted :) Good answer either way.

Comment: Edited answer, seems you were right, but the extra step was to set the option in resharper. Kudos.

Answer (score 4):

Your `IsNullOrEmpty()`-method seems to be an own invention since the original one is a static method of `System.String` and not an extension method. ReSharper isn't able to figure that one out though if you use the original one it will see that no `null`-values can make it past.

```
var str = value as string;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    return;

var unicorn = str.Contains("unicorn");
```

Comment: Make sure you use a capitalised "S" at String.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: @Matthijs Why? Both are completely valid and compile to `System.String`.

Comment: @dav_i: I swear I just saw IsNullOrEmpty not being available for lowercase string. My mistake, sorry!