# Code contracts together with frameworks not using it

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, resharper, code-contracts

I've got this code:

```
return session.Query<Payment>()
    .OrderBy(payment => payment.Created)
    .Skip((page - 1)*pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToArray();
```

Since NHibernate's Query method don't have any Contract.Ensures, I get this warning:

> CodeContracts: requires unproven: source != null

To fix it, I write this:

```
var query = session.Query<Payment>();
Contract.Assume(query != null);
return query
    .OrderBy(payment => payment.Created)
    .Skip((page - 1)*pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToArray();
```

Is this the right way to do it? Now Resharper thinks query can be null since I compare it to null.

> Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the right way to do it. Resharper doesn't understand Code Contracts by default, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929859/resharper-possible-null-assignment-when-using-microsoft-contracts/1693080#1693080) to fix that.

You might want to make a `Query` method inside your library which just calls NHibernate's `Query` but also has an `Ensures` contract, to save you having to use `Assume` everywhere.

Something like (I'm guessing the types here):

```
static IQueryable<T> MyQuery<T>(this Session s)
{
    Contract.Requires(s != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IQueryable<T>>() !=  null);

    var result = s.Query<T>();
    Contract.Assume(result != null);
    return result;
}
```